# How do I create a bleed for a doughnut shaped design? (A Collar for a Keg)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design, bleed, diecut

I'm very new to this and I've searched around and found one specific thread that almost answered my question but maybe I'm not entirely sure that I know what I'm looking for.

I have a design that will be printed and cut out (die-cut, I assume?) to the edge of the outer circle and then also a small circle in the center to create the collar for the top of the keg (looks like a doughnut).

I've watched lots of tutorials on creating a die-cut line which I have placed on the outer edge of the circle and the also on the inner parts where it will be cut out, but what about the bleed?

For the bleed specific dimensions, I can create them within the document but then it's rectangle or square, is it possible to create it around the circle - or does that matter? For now I've just extended the stroke of the outer circle a bit further than the cut contour line.

The company that i've created this design for did not give me any specifications from the printing company they use and I called the company and they really said as long as the bleed is fine and text is converted. So maybe I don't have a lot to go on either.

I appreciate any and all feedback that can help me get my design over to the printer.

Here is a picture to show what I'm looking at:

[image]

Comment: Pink circles are the cut lines and green circles are the bleed right?

Comment: I'd just fill it with yellow. It is *not* mandatory that bleeds follow the same contour as a trim, just so long as there *is* a minimum bleed amount in all appropriate areas.

Comment: I would say your file is setup correctly for printing. I usually use .125" bleed and even then I could probably use less bleed and be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept is right as AndrewH said. 3-5 mm wil be fine. (The distance form the magenta circle to the green one)

Just two things.

1. I would add cut lines on the gray square. I do not know how the sheet will be arranged to fit several circles or not, but if you are printing one by one or using rows and colums this marks will help to align the cut. Put them i a separated layer.

[image]

2. If the distance from the magenta circle and the circle in the design is too small, any misaligment will be evident. It is less evident if you have more distance to the final border.